# Mount VHD as ReadOnly

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, vhd, windows-server-backup

So I have the following scenario - two servers, one is Web server, another is a Backup server. Both running Windows Server 2012 R2

I have a mapped drive on Web referencing Backup I have a VHD I created on the Map drive, physically located on Backup that is being used by Web in order for Windows Server Backup to do nightly images to this VHD. The idea is to have the images physically stored on the Backup server, but performed from the Web server.

I have this VHD showing as a real drive in My PC on Web.

I'd like to mount this VHD as Read Only on the Backup server so I can take a peak every now and then to make sure the backups are showing up / access if necessary.

The problem is when I try to mount the VHD on the Backup as Read Only I receive "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

I'm suspecting they are saying this because its mounted on Web.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can accomplish what i'm hoping to accomplish or if its not possible.

FYI - HyperV/VM backups aren't a possibility in this scenario.

Comment: This sounds like a convoluted way of going about this. Why not just add the VHD to the Backup server as an additional virtual hard drive and have the Web server backup to it as a network location. Then you could just browse the backup files directly from the Backup server without having to mount the VHD from either server.

Comment: I know, it does sound convoluted but this was the only way I could get Windows Server Backup to do incrementals on essentially a mapped drive (using the VHD). Because otherwise if you backup to a mapped drive/network share using Windows Server Backup they delete the contents of that share daily prior to backing up, which sucks...

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why hyperV backups aren’t possible? Veeam community edition can backup HyperV hosts

Answer (score 0):

Take a volume snapshot of the volume on which the VHD sits.  Then look in the snapshot and mount the snapshot of the VHD, read-only.  This will give you your peek.